# Distance of a point to a set and to its boundary

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Setup and Notation**: Fix $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $(X,d)$ be a metric space such that $X$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$ with no isolated points and metric $d$ is the Euclidean distance. Note that $X$ is not necessarily convex set (e.g., $X = \{0,1\} \times [0,1]$). For arbitrary subset $C \subset X$, I denote by $C^c$, $\mathrm{int}(C)$, $\mathrm{cl}(C)$, and $\partial C$ the complement, interior, closure, and boundary of $C$, respectively. In addition, for arbitrary point $y \in X$, the set $B(y;r) := \{z \in X \mid d(y,z) < r\}$ is an open ball with center $y$ and radius $r$, and $d(y,C):= \inf_{z \in C} d(y,z)$ is the distance of point $y \in X$ to set $C$.

**Question**: Consider a arbitrary *closed* subset $F \subset X$ such that both $F$ and $F^c$ are not dense in $X$. For every point $x \in F^c$, do we have $$d(x,F) = d(x,\partial F)?$$ If it is not, what is a counterexample?

**What I know**: If $X$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$, I believe that the equation holds. This is because in this case $(X,d)$ is a path metric space, which implies the result (see [When is distance to the boundary always less than that to the exterior?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678021/when-is-distance-to-the-boundary-always-less-than-that-to-the-exterior)). In addition, I know that similar questions had been asked at [Distance from a point to a set is attained on the boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153148/distance-from-a-point-to-a-set-is-attained-on-the-boundary?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Distance to the boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3701703/distance-to-the-boundary?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, the proofs given there also rely on the convexity of the underlying metric space. I'm interested in whether the equation holds when $X$ is not convex.

**My proof attempt**: Since $d(x,F) \leq d(x,\partial F)$ is obvious by definition, it suffices to  show that the other direction of inequality holds. Let $y \in X$ be a point such that $d(x,y) = d(x,F)$ and assume that $y \notin \partial F$ (i.e., $y \in \mathrm{int}(F)$). Then, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ with $B(y;\epsilon) \subset \mathrm{int}(F)$. The open ball contains points other than $y$ itself since $X$ has no isolated points. Thus, if we have
$$ B(x;d(x,y)) \cap B(y;\epsilon) \neq \emptyset,$$
there exists a point $y' \in \mathrm{int}(F)$ with $d(x,y') < d(x,y)$, which contradicts to the assumption that $d(x,y) = d(x,F)$. However, I cannot show that the two open balls intersect.

Any suggestions are welcome! Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems to me that your equation holds from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1153219/693577), given that $x\in X \setminus F \implies x \in \mathbb{R}^{p} \setminus F$.

Comment: @Joe Thank you for your consideration. However, I do not agree with your idea. I happened to come up with a counterexample. If you are interested, please see the answer column. If it is something wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Oh yes, I had not considered that $\partial F$ would be different in the subspace topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a counterexample. Let $X = [0,1] \times \{0,\frac{1}{2}\}$ equipped with Euclidean distance. Consider $F = \{(x_1,x_2) \in X \mid \frac{1}{2}x_1 - x_2 \geq 0\}$. By the definition of $X$, we have $F = \{(a,0) \mid a \in [0,1]\}\cup\{(1,\frac{1}{2})\}$. In addition, it holds that $\partial F = \{(1,\frac{1}{2})\}$. If we choose $x = (\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2})$, we obtain $d(x,\partial F) = d((\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}),(1,\frac{1}{2})) = \frac{3}{4}$ and $d(x,F) = d((\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}),(\frac{1}{4},0)) = \frac{1}{2}$.